# Global minimum of a function in a specified interval

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I've got the following definition of `fun1`.

```
epsilon = 10^(-8)
fun1[h_] := (2 epsilon*Abs[Cos[1]]/h ) + (h*Abs[Cos[1]]/2)
```

Let's say I want to find global minimum in `Interval[10^(-16), 1]`, how can I do it?

Comment: `Minimize` accepts constraints: `Minimize[{fun1[h], 10^-6 < h < 1}, h]` evaluates to `{Cos[1]/5000, {h -> 1/5000}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
epsilon = 10^(-8);
fun1[h_] = (2*epsilon*Abs[Cos[1]]/h) + (h*Abs[Cos[1]]/2);
h /. First@Solve[{fun1'[h] == 0, fun1''[h] > 0, 10^-6 < h < 1}, h]
1/5000
fun1[%]
Cos[1]/5000
```

This is the global minimum.

Comment: This code doesn't work for `10^-3 < h < 1`.

Comment: @Carl Woll  Try: `Minimize[{fun1[h], 10^-3 < h < 1}, h]` and the warning appears:"Minimize::wksol: Warning: there is no minimum in the region in which the objective function is defined and the constraints are satisfied; returning a result on the boundary."

Answer (score 5):

The most direct answer is to use [`MinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue):

```
MinValue[{fun1[h], 10^-16 < h < 1}, h]
```

> Cos[1]/5000

It is also possible to use [`Minimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Minimize) instead of [`MinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinValue) to find out both the minimum value and the location of the minimum. Another idea is to use [`FunctionRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionRange) to find the range of your function:

```
FunctionRange[{fun1[h], 10^-16 < h < 1}, h, y]
```

> Cos[1]/5000 <= y < (4000000000000000000000001 Cos[1])/20000000000000000